# Create 2d array from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have the following string :

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],]
```

How can I create a 2d array of strings from it ?

---

EDIT

I've removed html tags since they're not the problem here. Also I'd like to do it without using any additional libs to keep it lightweight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except from the HTML tags in it, it would be valid JSON. You could remove the HTML tags and parse it using any library that handles JSON, like jQuery:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(theString.replace(/<br\/>/g,''));
```

It would also be valid Javascript code with the HTML tags removed, so if you have full control over where the string comes from so that you are certain that it can never contain any harmful code, you could use the `eval` function to execute the string:

```
// Warning: 'eval' is subject to code injection vulnerabilities
var arr = eval(theString.replace(/<br\/>/g,''));
```

Comment: +1 for parseJSON (or equivalent), and the warning about eval.  Many people say to avoid eval like the plague.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to remove the     `<br/>` from the string. Then you should be able to do:

```
var my2darray = eval(mystring);
```

Comment: Didnt mention how to do the replace.